# Creating direct HTTP-request through YouTube Analytics API v2 to view the videos of the channel that were embedded on external sites

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, youtube-analytics-api, youtube-analytics

I am quite new in using Google APIs. So, the problem is that I am administrator of the YouTube channel (not the owner). And I would like to get the straffic sources that were embedded on external websites. So, I've created new project and formed a request through Google APIs Explorer. Here it is:

```
https://youtubeanalytics.googleapis.com/v2/reports?dimensions=insightTrafficSourceDetail&endDate=2018-12-12&filters=insightTrafficSourceType%3D%3DEXT_URL&ids=channel%3D%3D{MY_CHANNEL}&maxResults=25&metrics=views&sort=-views&startDate=2014-05-01&key={MY_API_KEY}
```

Here is the result:

```
200

- Show headers -

{
 "kind": "youtubeAnalytics#resultTable",
 "columnHeaders": [
  {
   "name": "insightTrafficSourceDetail",
   "columnType": "DIMENSION",
   "dataType": "STRING"
  },
  {
   "name": "views",
   "columnType": "METRIC",
   "dataType": "INTEGER"
  }
 ],
 "rows": [
  [
   "vk.com",
   2399
  ],
  [
   "unknown",
   872
  ],
  [
   "yandex.ru",
   23
  ]
```

But when I try to write the request into the browser address bar directly, it says:

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": 401,
    "message": "Request is missing required authentication credential. Expected OAuth 2 access token, login cookie or other valid authentication credential. See https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/devconsole-project.",
    "errors": [
      {
        "message": "Request is missing required authentication credential. Expected OAuth 2 access token, login cookie or other valid authentication credential. See https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/devconsole-project.",
        "domain": "global",
        "reason": "unauthorized"
      }
    ],
    "status": "UNAUTHENTICATED"
  }
}
```

I pushed into the {API_KEY} field from [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1RM3d.png)

But, unfortunately, the result is such as provided above. What am I doing wrong? Can you provide the step-by-step instruction to get the right HTTP-request for my aim, as I counld'nt find it? Thank you!

Comment: It means that the action you're trying to do requires [Youtube OAuth 2.0 Authorization](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/authentication) where a mere API_KEY is not enough. Additonal reference - [Creating OAuth 2.0 credentials](https://developers.google.com/youtube/registering_an_application#Create_OAuth2_Tokens) and [Sample API Requests](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/sample_requests) too.

Comment: I've created the OAuth 2.0 client IDs in 'Credentials' of my API.
So, I've tried to create the request using the required parameters from the link you provided.

Comment: In the end I've formed a request: `https://youtubeanalytics.googleapis.com/v2/reports?dimensions=insightTrafficSourceDetail&endDate=2018-12-12&filters=insightTrafficSourceType%3D%3DEXT_URL&ids=channel%3D%3D{CHANNEL}&maxResults=25&metrics=views&sort=-views&startDate=2014-05-01&key={MY_API_KEY}&client_id={MY_API_CLIENT_ID}&redirect_uri=http://localhost:8080/oauth2callback&scope=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/yt-analytics.readonly`

Comment: So, I still don't understand how to create a valid HTTP-request, solving my problem